Testing for the type of alcohol
How can I test if the mixture I have contains ethanol or isopropyl (mixture is 70% alcohol and 30% purified water)? Will a simple "salting out expuriment" work (adding salt and seeing whether the mixture separated or not)? Or is there a better way to check it?

You could try the Lucas test. Although, 70% alcohol makes me think this is hand sanitizer, and most labels that have just "alcohol" written on them usually refer to ethanol.

What is "salting out expurimenta"? Are you just testing if the sample has alcohol or are you determining the type of alcohol? In any case, the ester test is a solid test. Each ester has a distinct smell.

@NilayGhosh that was a typo... Sorry... I've fixed it and added an explanation to the question. I'll also write it here "salting out expuriment" = adding salt and seeing whether the mixture separates or not

I have converted my comment into an answer. But it would still be helpful if you can clarify my second question.

Yes, I know that there is alcohol and I also know it's concentration (70%) and I want to determine the type of the alcohol

Salting out would work for both, so hard to decide, unless you can compare to verified 70% solution of both, or at least one of them.

I understand from your previous post that you have a home chemistry kit, so you delve into home chemistry. There are many tests for presence of alcoholic group, but the best test for you would be the ester test where you react the alcoholic sample with carboxylic acid to give ester which has a fruity smell. Each ester has its distinct smell, so you would be able to identify what alcohol is there in your sample.
